# Find a derived class in a list of its base class

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

So I have a List of BaseClass and I've filled it with several instances of derived classes (only one of each derived class) so that we have something like:

```
List<BaseClass> myList = new List<BaseClass>();

myList.Add(new DerivedClassA());
myList.Add(new DerivedClassB());
myList.Add(new DerivedClassC());
```

Now I want to be able to search myList with something like this:

```
public void FindClass (BaseClass class){ //class is a derived class
   //find index or object of type class
   //so that if class is a DerivedClassB
   //we return the first DerivedClassB in myList 
}
```

Is this possible? I know I can give each DerivedClass a name property and find it by it's name but I don't want to have to do that.

Comment: You could use `is` `keyword` to determine if it is of derived type.

Comment: Do you really want `FindClass` to require an *instance* to be passed as a parameter? Would a `Type` not be more suitable here? (Either as a plain parameter or as a generic type parameter)

Comment: Be aware that, although Domysee's answer is a bit faster than 3dd's solution (see [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vy2qnw)) it's less robust against changes. When you subtype from `DerivedClass*` and add instances of this sub-subtype to the list, then `GetType()` wont traverse the inheritance hierarchie like the `is` operator (resp. `OfType<T>()`) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass in an instance of `DerivedClassB`, you can find all instances of `DerivedClassB` by comparing the actual type of the instance passed in and of the instances in the list:

```
public IEnumerable<BaseClass> FindClass (BaseClass @class){ 
    return myList.Where(c => c.GetType() == @class.GetType());
}
```

Comment: You should change your 'class' parameter something like @class.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution would be to use 'OfType<>' to filter the list

```
public class Base { }

public class DerivedA : Base { }
public class DerivedB : Base { }

List<Base> instances = new List<Base>();
instances.Add(new DerivedA());
instances.Add(new DerivedB());

 var results = instances.OfType<DerivedA>().FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT - This is a way of creating a method that would do the search

```
T Find<T>() where T : Base {
    return _Instances.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace ´DerivedA´with the input parameter, instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen yes it is, please see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `is` operator. It tells you if an object is of a given type. Add a little LINQ and you get:

```
var firstB = myList
        .Where(c => c is DerivedClassB)
        .First();
```

Comment: Indeed. My bad. I didn't compile this. I'll fix it up.

Comment: Just use `myList.First(c => c is DerivedClassB)` if you do this.